# Apache Virtual Host Gets www.domain.com but not domain.com

Tags: apache-2.2

I have this in my sites-available apache2 virtual host file:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName  domain.com
   ServerAlias www.domain.com

...
</VirtualHost>
```

Why does apache send requests from www.domain.com to the correct path, but domain.com gets sent to the default virtual host?

Update:  The reason domain.com gets sent to the default virtual host is because the hostname of the machine automatically gets sent to default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Obvious question -- is the DNS for www and non-www the same?)

For debugging purposes the -S flag is useful to check the config as the apache service itself sees it.

*Debian based world:*

```
apache2 -S
```

*Redhat based world:*

```
httpd -S
```

*and another example:*

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:2)
         port 80 namevhost mydomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1:16)
         port 80 namevhost myotherdomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain2:1
...etc
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd check to see if you have the proper DNS records for domain.com and www.domain.com - where there is 1 main A record, and then a CNAME for the other.

You can do lookups with the tools at [network-tools.com](http://network-tools.com)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have DNS entries set for www to point to domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a servername directive outside of the < virtualhost > section?